# How can I differentiate two .txt files without open & read the file?

Tags: python, function, txt

```
def load_data(path: str, format: Literal['type0', 'type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4'] = 'type0') -> Data:
if format not in {'type0', 'type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4'}:
    raise ValueError(f"Incorrect format `{format}` specified for load_data()")



if format == 'type0':
    if path.lower().endswith('.pdf'):
        data = parse_type1(path)
    elif path.lower().endswith('.csv') or path.lower().endswith('.d'):
        data = parse_type2(path)
    elif path.lower().endswith('.txt'):
        data = parse_type3(path)
    elif path.lower().endswith('.txt'):
        data = parse_type4(path)
    else:
        raise Exception("Unknown file format in load_data(), consider specifying the format instead of using `type0`")
elif format == 'type1':
    data = parse_type1(path)
elif format == 'type2':
    data = parse_type2(path)
elif format == 'type3':
    data = parse_type3(path)
elif format == 'type4':
    data = parse_type4(path)
    
assert data.data.shape[0] == data.wavelength.shape[0], 'Parsing raw data by load_data() yields inconsistent shapes'
assert data.data.shape[1] == data.time.shape[0], 'Parsing raw data by load_data() yields inconsistent shapes'

return data`
```

Given the following function, as you can see, I link this main function to other sub-functions for each specific file type. I have a new file type, namely a txt file (type4), which has the same txt format as type3. I would like to be able to distinguish between the two files without necessarily having to open them. The files are similar but have differences. For example, type3 has data separated by commas, while type4 has data separated by spaces. How can I modify the function so that type4 is not confused with type3, given that they have the same txt format?

Comment: This isn't possible without opening the files. It might be that you don't need to read the *entire* file, for example perhaps opening the file and reading a small portion is enough to tell you what you need to know.

Comment: (Don't think of opening a file in Python as being like "opening" a file in Excel or whatever, which probably does load the entire thing into memory. It's more like opening a book - you can open the book without having to read every page.)

Comment: i guess, you can do the word count to find difference!, if that comes under read, then idk a way!

Answer (score 2):

> distinguish between the two files without necessarily having to open
> them

This is not possible unless you are able to enforce names of said files to indicate difference

> type3 has data separated by commas, while type4 has data separated by
> spaces

You might find [`csv.Sniffer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) useful for determining that, observe that it might works by reading beginning of file rather than whole file, if you just want to know separator used in `file.txt` you might do

```
import csv
with open('file.txt', newline='') as file:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(file.read(1024))
print(dialect.delimiter)
```

however keep in mind that it is using certain heuristic so it might give wrong delimiter.

Answer (score -1):

If the files differ by having different column separators, the space delimited files do not have comas in the values and vice versa, then you do not even need python for this.

```
grep  --max-count=1 ' ' file_pattern > files_with_spaces.txt
grep  --max-count=1 ',' file_pattern > files_with_comas.txt
```

But to check that the given file is properly formatted you may use existing python libraries checking number of columns, data types etc.
Take a look at polars i.e. You can read files one by one  using:

```
coma_df = pl.read_csv(file_name, separator=",")
space_df = pl.read_csv(file_name, separator=" ")
```

wrapping it into try/except and checking the numbers of columns.